# SMJobBless works only with kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, need kSMDomainUserLaunchd

Tags: macos, cocoa, smjobbless

The documentations states, that with **SMJobBless** you can use only **kSMDomainSystemLaunchd**

```
SMJobBless(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, (CFStringRef)label, authRef, (CFErrorRef *)error);
```

But how to create a LaunchAgent inside LaunchAgents/ in users library, that executes on user login using SMJobBless or similar approach?

Comment: Hi @peter, have you found a solution finally?

Comment: Nope, in the end i didn't used SMJobBless as the app didn't needed to be on AppStore

Comment: Hi @peter, as far as i know even when using SMJobBless, app still wont be eligible for app store publishing. How you finally implemented the launch agent? Just standalone binary with installer? (if it's not secret of course).

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but maybe someone has the same issue.

There are 2 main approaches to add an agent: using system API (`ServiceManagement` framework) or command-line tool (`launchctl`).

Using API

`SMJobBless` creates a daemon—process, running under root. If you wish to create an agent—process, running under another user, use the `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` function. There is a slight difference between these functions:

1. `SMJobBless` registers an executable and `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` accepts bundle id as main parameter, so for an agent you need to create a Cocoa app.
2. `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` is much easier to set up.
3. `SMJobBless` copies the executable to `Library/PrivilegedHelperTools` and launches it from there, not from your bundle. `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` launches the agent from your bundle, without copying it.
4. `SMJobBless` requires the user to enter admin password; `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` doesn't bother the user with anything, it does not require root rights.

Using launchctl

`SMLoginItemSetEnabled` registeres the agent only for the current user. If you need to add an agent, which will be launched automatically for any user, that logges in, put a configuration `.plist` file into `/Library/LaunchAgents` (you'll need root rights to do that). In order to load it immediately use `launchctl` tool (from code—via `NSTask`). Documentation on configuration files: `man launchd.plist`.